# In an ATIS broadcast, is the visibility in statute or nautical miles?

Tags: weather, atis

I think I remember seeing somewhere that since it's an observation at the surface, statute miles are used for the visibility. Would be nice if someone had a reference.

Comment: In Europe, it's in meters.

Comment: ...not just in Europe, practically everywhere outside America. Thus, lacking the country-specific tag, metres should be the correct default answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAA has this handy [chart](https://www.weather.gov/media/okx/Aviation/TAF_Card.pdf) to decode METARs (which are the printed version of the ATIS) and TAFs.

> Prevailing visibility; in U.S., Statute Miles & fractions; above 6
>   miles in TAF Plus6SM. (Or, 4-digit minimum visibility in meters and as
>   required, lowest value with direction)